# Why is GRUB loading inconsistently?

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on a ThinkPad S120 (Yoga 12). GRUB is accessed, as is fairly standard, by pressing `Shift` on boot. I was having some difficulty booting into Ubuntu so decided to try using GRUB to revert to an earlier Linux kernel to see if that would help.

I've tried to boot into GRUB perhaps 20 times now. The attempts result in three different behaviours which, if tried in succession, seem to occur randomly:

- Behaviour 1: Sometimes GRUB will load successfully.
- Behaviour 2: Sometimes the text "GRUB LOADING." appears at the top of the display and then the machine hangs, without the GRUB menu ever actually appearing.
- Behaviour 3: Sometimes I am presented simply with a blank display.

On observing any of those halting behaviours, I am forced to power off the machine and try to boot it into GRUB again. However, bizarrely, if the machine is left untouched and powered off for about 20 minutes, GRUB loads successfully.

Why is this behaviour happening? Why is it happening inconsistently? Why in hell does *time* between attempts seem to make a difference?

Comment: reinstall  grub and try again

Comment: @Hossein I'd like to understand the problem though. Do you have any ideas why *time* seems to make a difference? Like, if the boot to GRUB fails and I try to boot to GRUB again within a minute or so, it fails again. However, if I leave it for 20 minutes, it then works. Why could this be? How could I try to find out why there is this behaviour?